# Different maven-metadata.xml when using Artifactory as maven snapshot repo and Java URL connect

Tags: maven, artifactory, user-agent

We are using internally Artifactory/7.41.7 for our maven build results. One of the repos is a snapshot repository, which is uploaded on every push and build. These build results are meant to be only temporary. The folder structure on Artifactory looks like in the image below
[image: snapshot result]

Now I wanted to write a little tool, which downloads the latest build from the repository in Artifactory. The information about the artifacts in this build are described in the maven-metadata.xml. Which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
  <version>1.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20221108.105509</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20221108105513</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.00-20221108.105509-2</value>
        <updated>20221108105509</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.00-20221108.105509-2</value>
        <updated>20221108105509</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.00-20221108.105509-2</value>
        <updated>20221108105509</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      ...
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

It looks like an easy thing to parse the xml and then download the required artifact. So I wrote this little test script in java:

```
var myUri = new URL("https://artifactory/snapshots/.../1.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml");
var httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) myUri.openConnection();
httpCon.addRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
try (InputStream is = httpCon.getInputStream()) {
   var xmlResult = new String(is.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   System.out.println(xmlResult);
}
```

The result of this request was very weird, because the snapshotVersion information was missing:

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
  <version>1.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20221108.105509</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20221108105513</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

**But if you are using CURL or any browser on the same URI then you get the proper result!**

What the HELL???

Why do I get different results based on the tool I am using?!

After many many WTFs and other tries I found out that the result depends on the user agent!
The default user agent of java applications is **Java/<version>** (according to [Oracle Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/core/java-networking.html#GUID-5A3F83F9-1335-46AD-B7DF-8A1CA0D88C89)).
So I enhanced the script with a different user agent:

```
var myUri = new URL("https://artifactory/snapshots/.../1.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml");
var httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) myUri.openConnection();
httpCon.addRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
httpCon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "curl/1.0"); //<- custom user agent!!!
try (InputStream is = httpCon.getInputStream()) {
   var xmlResult = new String(is.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   System.out.println(xmlResult);
}
```

The result now is correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
  <version>1.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20221108.105509</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20221108105513</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.00-20221108.105509-2</value>
        <updated>20221108105509</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      ...
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Why I am getting different results from Artifactory depending on the user agent?

I am expecting the **SAME** xml content independent from the user agent!

I also asked Artifactory support, but I was not able to get a useful answer. The only things I know are:

- The behaviour is not described in the [Artifactory Docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Documentation)
- The behaviour is not defined nor described in [Maven Docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-Non-uniqueSnapshotDeployments)

Does anyone else having an answer to this?
If not then I hope this question will save some time in similar scenarios.